# Will Bool be bridged to NSNumber when calling setObject(_:forKey:) on NSUserDefaults?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

In `NSUserDefaults` Class Reference, I find the following sentences:

> func setObject(_ value: AnyObject?, forKey defaultName: String)
>
> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.

If I call the method with a boolean value in Swift, will it be bridged to `NSNumber`? Do I *have to* call `setBool` instead? And what about `Int`, `Float` and `Double`?

PS: I tried it in my project. When I called `objectForKey() as! Bool`, it sometimes crashed while sometimes not. I am not sure what happened, so I asked this question.

Comment: Did you try it to see what would happen? That should be the first step before asking a "what will happen..." question.

Comment: @BryanOakley In fact I have tried it. When I call `objectForKey() as! Bool`, it sometimes crashes, but sometimes not. I am not sure what happened so I asked this question.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information. Though, I think "it crashes randomly" is a good reason heed the advice in the documentation.

Comment: @yzyzsun now have answered your question

Comment: The benefit of `boolForKey`/ `integerForKey` is that it returns a non-optional (`false` / `0` for *no value*).

Answer (score 1):

Swift Bool is bridged to Objective-C NSNumber. If you don't want to rely on implicit casting (and you should not, as it will go away in Swift 3), cast it yourself by saying `myBool as NSNumber`. But I assure you that in your code, it *is* being implicitly cast.

Coming back the other way, NSNumber is bridged to Swift Bool, but it must be cast down explicitly somehow. If you say `as! Bool`, you are asking to crash — you are asking to crash *any* time you say `as!` — so if you would prefer not to crash, don't say that. There are many other ways to cast safely, including `boolForKey`.

The crash, however, has nothing to do with the way you called `setObject:forKey:`. It has to do with the fact that you are saying `as!` coming back the other way, and at that time, there either is no such key or that key's value is not an NSNumber wrapping a Bool. You have not shown the whole of your code (indeed, you have not shown any of your code), so there is nothing constructive to be said about that.

Comment: I did not mention the crash at first, just because I am not sure if there is any mistake otherwhere. Your assurance gives me reason to review the whole code myself. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to store a BOOL, you have to call `setBool`, as `setObject` takes an object as argument.

BOOL, Int, Float, etc. are primitive types that are not objects.

Comment: I think in Swift they cannot be simply called *primary types* any more. We can see that Bool, Int, Float, etc. are actually structs, and sometimes they can be converted into the corresponding Cocoa types implicitly. So I wonder whether they are bridged to NSNumber here.

Comment: By primary, I wanted to differenciate with Objects.  But you're right, but I don't think they are bridged or if so it's buggy, it's why you have random crashes